# How to map process file descriptor to a java object

Tags: java, debugging, file-descriptor, resource-leak

I have a web app which leaks file descriptors. In production environment number of file descriptors on a java process grows slowly over time and after few months it runs out of file descriptors. Current limit of file descriptors is rather high, 10240.

When looking at java process, this is how list of file descriptor looks:

```
# ls -l /proc/32526/fd |wc -l
9558

# ls -l /proc/32526/fd
lr-x------ 1 userx userx 64 Apr 23 12:21 1229 -> /data/s1-js2-tier2-store6/52d/2ed/f73/1c80d154a055e5e
lr-x------ 1 userx userx 64 Apr 23 12:21 1230 -> /data/s1-js2-tier2-store6/52d/9aa/ad3/1c80d154a0688a6
lr-x------ 1 userx userx 64 Apr 23 12:21 1231 -> /data/s1-js2-tier2-store4/522/9c8/543/1c81a0c37763880
lr-x------ 1 userx userx 64 Apr 23 12:21 1232 -> /data/s1-js2-tier2-store6/52d/78c/4f3/1c80d154a06308c
lr-x------ 1 userx userx 64 Apr 23 12:21 1239 -> /data/s1-js2-tier2-store6/530/b88/753/1c80901a6d6541f (deleted)
```

What I would like to do is select one file descriptor, and then somehow map it to an object in a live JVM so that I can explore which objects are left behind and who holds the reference to objects with file descriptors attached.

I wanted to connect to live JVM with Eclipse, but to do that I need to restart JVM to add debug ports/params but then will need to wait months for same situation to appear.

How can I do that without restarting JVM? Are there any dump tools that can help me for this specific case?

Comment: Your main goal is to find the leak and remove it from the source code or you don't have the sources and need to hack?

Comment: Main goal is to find the leak and fix it. I have source code.

Comment: We had an application developed by another company and I had the same issue. Not sure if it helps you, but I fixed it using eclipse's full search. I searched for `FileReader` and `FileWriter` and I found a few places where the files were open and read, but never closed. So I just put it into a `try/catch/finally` block and the issue was gone. But you might have a more complicated issue. Also try to search for `Input/OutputStream`s, or directly `java.io`.I know it doesn't answer the question, but maybe it helps.

Comment: Which JVM implementation is being used to host the application?

Comment: Sun/Oracle JDK 1.7.0_51

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a heap dump of the VM.

If you are on jdk 1.7 you can connect to the JVM even without prior setup of the debugging. You should be able to get the heap dump via jmap on the shell.

```
jmap -dump:format=b,file=<FILENAME> <PID>
```

will do this for you.

Afterwards you can load the heap dump into Eclipse MAT and analyze from there. If the leak is significant enough, then it is probably not very hard to detect it with the default reports.

Comment: This is not quite an answer to the original question, how to map a file descriptor to a java object that holds it ;)

Comment: You asked for a ***"dump tool"*** that can help you. While there's no single tool for it (at least that I know of), I think that jmap + MAT will help you achieve your goal. MAT will allow you to filter for File references first, and then you can walk up the object graph to see ***"who holds the reference to objects with file descriptors attached"***.